# Display multiple values in col on barplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, google-colaboratory

So I have a column of my dataframe that looks like this:

10 first rows of the column expeditions['first_ascent_country']

```
0    New Zealand, USA, UK
1                      UK
2                  France
3               UK, Nepal
4                   India
5               W Germany
6                   Spain
7               W Germany
8            Japan, Nepal
9            Japan, Nepal
```

It gives information on which country climbed a mountain first. I want to display those countries in a barplot to show which ones discovered more, but I get this... How do I separate the countries using a comma?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi0y0.png)

How can I make it so that the rows with multiple countries are displayed on the chart separately? I have been looking everywhere but idk how to make it work...
Sorry if my question is stupid but I'm pretty new to working with dataframes.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `peaks['first_ascent_country'].head(10)`, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['peak_ascent_country'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts().plot.barh()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Step by step:

```
>>> df['peak_ascent_country'].str.split(', ')
0    [New Zealand, USA, UK]
1                      [UK]
2                  [France]
3               [UK, Nepal]
4                   [India]
5               [W Germany]
6                   [Spain]
7               [W Germany]
8            [Japan, Nepal]
9            [Japan, Nepal]
Name: peak_ascent_country, dtype: object
```

```
>>> df['peak_ascent_country'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
0    New Zealand
0            USA
0             UK
1             UK
2         France
3             UK
3          Nepal
4          India
5      W Germany
6          Spain
7      W Germany
8          Japan
8          Nepal
9          Japan
9          Nepal
Name: peak_ascent_country, dtype: object
```

```
>>> df['peak_ascent_country'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
UK             3
Nepal          3
W Germany      2
Japan          2
New Zealand    1
USA            1
France         1
India          1
Spain          1
Name: peak_ascent_country, dtype: int64
```